# How to fix "Skype can't connect"?

Tags: 14.04, skype

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and had skype 4.3 installed, worked without any issues. Today, just like that, I always get the error

```
Skype can't connect
```

when I try to log in. I can log in to the skype account on skype.com, I removed the folder `.Skype` and I re-installed skype multiple times, using `apt-get` and by directly installing the 'deb' file from `skype.com` But nothing is working. I just can't log in.

And idea what else I can try?

Comment: Same thing happened to me just now. While I can connect with web.skype.com

Comment: Well, it works kind of, but you cannot make calls...

Comment: Maybe because of the new skype version `SkypeForLinuxAlpha`. Maybe they want you to start using it from now on instead of the old version.

Comment: Try installing the new version and see if that works.

Comment: @Raphael: No, 4.3 works fine at this time, at least for me.

Answer (score 3):

Don't mess with any of your files.

The issue is on skypes end currently, if it's urgent you can try to connect via the website version of skype at http://web.skype.com