# Since 14 8 2016 Skype can't connect from Ubuntu 16.04. How can I solve it?

Tags: 16.04, skype

Since today, 14 Aug 2016, **Skype** can't connect from my Ubuntu 16.04 x64 installation.
I've tried removing it and reinstalling it without success. I was able to use it 3 days ago.

Any suggestion?

I'm running kernel 4.7.

Comment: [Same question](http://askubuntu.com/q/812095/119531) has already been asked once  (or maybe more) today. Rest assured that you are not the only one experiencing the glitch. Maybe because THEY want you to start using the new [SkypeforLinuxAlpha](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299). Try installing the new version and try again.

Comment: Skype works for me with no problems.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Here is an [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/using-old-skype-linux-app-cant-connect-youre-not-alone) article that addresses a similar issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the skype login servers are down.
You might have some luck with the web client.

web.skype.com
http://downdetector.com/status/skype

Comment: I'll try later, if this is the case will mark this as answer.

Comment: Now all is good without changing anything... looked like servers were down...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the most-recent version of skype installed?

- open Skype
- click on "skype" (menu-entry)
- About Skype
- Skype (TM) Version 4.3.0.37

If not let skype check for updates (menu-entry below the "about Skype"-entry)

Comment: It's already the latest version... might need to install alpha...

Answer (score 0):

Try to log in via another account.

E.g. if you were using an original skype account, use a windows-live account or vice-versa.